# How to use viridis in matplotlib 1.4

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I want to use the colormap "viridis" (http://bids.github.io/colormap/), and I won't be updating to the development version 1.5 quite yet.  Thus, I have downloaded `colormaps.py` from https://github.com/BIDS/colormap.  Unfortunately, I'm not able to make it work.  This is what I do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

import colormaps as cmaps

img=mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')
lum_img = np.flipud(img[:,:,0])

plt.set_cmap(cmaps.viridis)
imgplot = plt.pcolormesh(lum_img)
```

This gives me a `ValueError`, the traceback ending with,

> ValueError: Colormap viridis is not recognized. Possible values are: Spectral, summer, coolwarm, ...

(And then the complete list of originally installed colormaps.)

Any thoughts on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To set `viridis` as your colormap using `set_cmap`, you must register it first:

```
import colormaps as cmaps
plt.register_cmap(name='viridis', cmap=cmaps.viridis)
plt.set_cmap(cmaps.viridis)

img=mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')
lum_img = np.flipud(img[:,:,0])
imgplot = plt.pcolormesh(lum_img)
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I need.

Answer (score 12):

Rather than using `set_cmap`, which requires a `matplotlib.colors.Colormap` instance, you can set the `cmap` directly in the `pcolormesh` call

(`cmaps.viridis` is a `matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

import colormaps as cmaps

img=mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')
lum_img = np.flipud(img[:,:,0])

imgplot = plt.pcolormesh(lum_img, cmap=cmaps.viridis)
```

Comment: What would cause `ImportError: No module named colormaps` ?

Comment: @Annan: Have you downloaded `colormaps.py` from https://github.com/BIDS/colormap?

Comment: @tom Thanks for replying to my query. I didn't realise it was a separate module (I've been jumping around a few questions about the 'viridis' cmap and did not fully read the question you were answering). I actually fixed the issue by updating matplotlib to the latest version - which for me is 1.5.3.

Comment: @ Annan. Yes, obviously the best way to get `viridis` is to use the latest version of `matplotlib` (i.e. any version `>= 1.5`). However, this question and answer were about using `viridis` with a version of matplotlib (1.4) which did not include the viridis colormap

Answer (score 3):

What I did is to just copy the

```
_viridis_data = [[0.267004, 0.004874, 0.329415],
                 [0.268510, 0.009605, 0.335427],
                 [0.269944, 0.014625, 0.341379],
                 :
                 [0.983868, 0.904867, 0.136897],
                 [0.993248, 0.906157, 0.143936]]
```

from https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/blob/master/colormaps.py

and add:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

viridis = ListedColormap(_viridis_data, name='viridis')

plt.register_cmap(name='viridis', cmap=viridis)
plt.set_cmap(viridis)
```

Answer (score 2):

Download the colormaps.py from [here](https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/blob/master/colormaps.py),then:

```
import os,sys
scriptpath = "/Your downloading path/colormap-master/"
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(scriptpath))
import colormaps as cmaps
```

Done!