# Using builtin colormap from dates in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have some time series data that I want to plot, and I want to use color scaling to represent the age of a datapoint. I can successfully get the colour bar working:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=10)
y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=10)
dates = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", end="2000-01-10", freq="D")

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y, "dates": dates})

sc = plt.scatter(df["x"], df["y"], c=[date2num(i) for i in df["dates"]])
plt.colorbar(sc)
plt.savefig("dates.png")
```

However, I don't understand how to use the [built in colour maps](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html), like the perceptually uniform or sequential colour maps. How do I use a built in colour map as `c` when calling scatter?

Comment: Does adding `cmap` option to `scatter`, e.g. `sc = plt.scatter(df["x"], df["y"], c=[date2num(i) for i in df["dates"], cmap=plt.cm.viridis)` do what you want? If you are pre-matplotlib 1.5 then check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484453/how-to-use-viridis-in-matplotlib-1-4 to get the Perceptually Uniform Sequential colourmaps

Comment: That did exactly what I was hoping it would! Thanks! If you want to answer the question with that comment, I'll accept it.

Comment: Done, although I think is is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063876/matplotlib-colorbar-for-scatter#6065493

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `cmap` option to scatter: `sc = plt.scatter(df["x"], df["y"], c=[date2num(i) for i in df["dates"], cmap=plt.cm.viridis)`. You can specify the range of the colorbar with the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments.

If you are pre-matplotlib 1.5 then check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484453/how-to-use-viridis-in-matplotlib-1-4) answer to get the Perceptually Uniform Sequential colourmaps.